# What does this define do?

Tags: c++

What does this define do, and how would I use it?

```
#define UNUSED(VAR) (void)&(VAR)
```

Does it require a definition anywhere? This is in the header.

**edit** - I don't really understand what is going on here. is this a macro'd cast to void? doesn't that negate the variable?

Comment: Yes, it's a macro that casts to `void`. What do you mean with "negate the variable"?

Comment: wrong word, I mean make it null.. i guess. What does casting to void do if it's an int for example?

Comment: it does nothing. That's why it's used here. It's an explicit way of saying "do nothing with this variable".

Answer (score 2):

It exists to avoid warnings for unused parameters and variables. Simply casting to `void` is enough for that: it uses the variable, and the cast *usually* does nothing. I can only guess what the `&` operator is used for here. Maybe it's to [prevent a conversion operator from being called](http://ideone.com/zqN9c). However, it doesn't [prevent an overloaded `operator&` from being called](http://ideone.com/NfhjK). Or it could be to make sure it is only used on variables, but that is not perfect either: [it can be used on expressions that produce references.](http://ideone.com/gcXHs)

Answer (score 1):

The intention is to prevent yourself getting a compiler warning about an unused parameter.

The better way is just to leave it anonymous, e.g.

```
void do_stuff( int x, int );
```

the 2nd parameter is unused on this case. It may need to be there for some overload purpose.

With regards to using it for a local variable - you have to ask yourself, why declare a local variable and then not use it?

Well the answer may be that you use pre-processors in the code in such a way that a variable will sometimes be used but not always. However it may not always be practical to pre-process out its existence.

The fact you declare a variable unused does not make it an error if you really do use it.

Comment: There are two problems with leaving it anonymous. First, that only works if no code paths or conditionally compiled blocks use the variable. If some do, leaving it anonymous will cause those that do to fail. Second, leaving it anonymous makes the code much harder to review, since it makes it difficult to tell what that variable held which is needed to determine if it's ignored safely in that code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a macro that can be used to stop the compiler complaining/warning about a variable that is delcared but not referenced.  It is common to achieve the same result with a compiler #pragma setting to disable such warnings globaly.

Answer (score 0):

It's for when you have you compiler produce warnings or errors if some variable remains unused. Using a define like this, you can insert a "no-op" that silences these warnings/errors if you checked the situation.

For example:

```
void foo()
{
  int x=0;
  UNUSED(x); // don't warn me that x is not actually being used
}
```